# iterate through hover on array jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, for-loop, hover

I have an array of badges...

```
[<div class=​"badge">​</div>​, <div class=​"badge">​</div>​, <div class=​"badge">​​</div>​]
```

and an array of arrows...

```
[<div class=​"arrow">​</div>​, <div class=​"arrow">​</div>​, <div class=​"arrow">​</div>​]
```

I'm trying to get the arrows to display when I hover over the badge so I have something like

```
$('.badge').hover(function() {
    $('.arrow').show();
}, function() {
    $('.arrow').hide();
});
```

I'm trying to isolate each individual badge and arrow to hover independently, but I can't seem to isolate it by $('.badge').first() or $('.arrow')[0]

This is the desired result at this [website](http://davidgumzchoi.github.io/Thinkful-37signals/), but I want to do so without having to use so many specific classes like badge1, badge2, badge3, and arrow1, arrow2, arrow3.

HTML

```
<div class="badge badge1 margin_right">  
    <div class="arrow arrow1 right" style="display: none;"></div>
    <img src="images/logo-bc.png" alt="basecamp"/>
    <h3><a href="#">Basecamp</a><span>®</span></h3>
    <h4>Manage Projects</h4>
    <p>Used by millions for project management.</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case the `arrow` is an descendant of the `badge` element, so what you need is to change the display of the `arrow` inside the `badge` when you hover a badge.

So

```
$('.badge').hover(function () {
    $(this).find('.arrow').show();
}, function () {
    $(this).find('.arrow').hide();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This might help you-

```
$.each([arr1, arr2], function() {
$.each(this, function(i, v) {
    // do something
});
});
```